# My component doesn't re-render when i switch his props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to render two charts changing their props by clicking a button, here is this part of the code:

```
<Button
                variant={ atualYearClicked ? "contained" : "outlined" }
                color="primary" 
                onClick={ () => setAtualYearClicked(true) }
              >
                2021
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant={ atualYearClicked ? "outlined" : "contained" }
                color="primary"
                onClick={ () => setAtualYearClicked(false) }
              >
                2020
              </Button>

{atualYearClicked ? <ChartAnnual year={2021} /> : <ChartAnnual year={2020} />}
```

As you can see i update a state(tried both local and global), and it passes a props to the component render accordingly to this props.

But when i click the 2020 button, doesnt change the chart, just nothing happens.

***Sorry for the wrong management of my post, i actually solved! I just put the year prop inside the useEffect and it updated. Sorry for the incovenience***

Comment: We would need more detail. I can't find anything wrong here.